# Does pytest support verifications?

Tags: python, mockito, pytest

Does pytest support verifications like mockito?

```
verify(dummy, atleast=1).foo()
```

https://code.google.com/p/mockito-python/wiki/Verifications#Verifying_Number_of_Invocations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pytest supports verification in the sense that you can use mockito with pytest. pytest does not provide a mocking library.

Specifically, since mockito's `VerificationError` is a subclass of `AssertionError`, tests run with pytest will fail appropriately if the verification fails.

```
>>> isinstance(mockito.VerificationError(), AssertionError)
True
```